# How do I change the pygame icon?

Tags: python, pygame, icons

Does anyone know how to change the pygame icon?
I found a thing on the pygame website that lets you do this, but when I try it, it just makes the pygame window very small.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

First load the icon image as a surface, then use `pygame.display.set_icon(surface)` to change the icon.

EDIT: Since the asker doesn't know what a surface is

From the docs at http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html

"A pygame Surface is used to represent any image. The Surface has a fixed resolution and pixel format. Call pygame.Surface() to create a new image object."

For example, if you used `screen = pygame.display.set_mode`, `screen` is a surface.

So when using `pygame.display.set_icon(surface)` you must first import an image as a pygame.Surface by using `a = pygame.image.load('image')` where `a` is the variable the surface will be stored and `'image'` is the directory to that image. Then you can set a to the icon by using `pygame.display.set_icon(surface)`. You can pass any surface, but it is desirable that it is 32x32.

More information here: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_icon

Answer (score 15):

```
programIcon = pygame.image.load('icon.png')

pygame.display.set_icon(programIcon)
```

This will set the icon of the Pygame window.

Answer (score 1):

You must be careful when setting a window icon. See [`pygame.display.set_icon()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_icon):

> [...] Some systems do not allow the window icon to change after it has been shown. This function can be called before `pygame.display.set_mode()` to create the icon before the display mode is set.

Set the icon before initializing the  window  `pygame.display.set_mode()`. e.g.:

```py
icon = pygame.image.load('my_icon.png') 
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption(‘my window’)
```

---

In addition, the size of the icon is limited:

> [...] You can pass any surface, but most systems want a smaller image around 32x32.

If the icon is not displayed, try a smaller icon.

---

Make sure that the resource (image) path and the working directory is correct.

The image file path has to be relative to the current working directory. The working directory is possibly different to the directory of the python file.

The name and path of the file can be get by [`__file__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#import-related-module-attributes). The current working directory can be get by [`os.getcwd()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) and can be changed by [`os.chdir(path)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html).

```py
import os

sourceFileDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
os.chdir(sourceFileDir)
```

An alternative solution is to find the absolute path.
If the image is relative to the folder of the python file (or even in the same folder), then you can get the directory of the file and join ([`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html)) the image filename. e.g.:

```py
import pygame
import os

# get the directory of this file
sourceFileDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

iconPath = os.path.join(sourceFileDir, 'my_icon.png')
icon = pygame.image.load(iconPath) 
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **pgzero** you can simply set global variable ICON to path to desired PNG file, like:

```
ICON = 'images/icon.png'
```

and pgzero will automatically replace default icon.

For more information see: https://github.com/lordmauve/pgzero/pull/128/files

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to make an object, say an icon, and in that variable you have to give the path of the image you want to set as icon.

```
icon = 'your image path'
```

(Make sure you put double backslashes when writing path because writing single might give you an error)
After that you have to write:

```
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
```

Make sure you have imported and installed pygame on your system
installation of pygame:
(if you are on windows):
hit windows+r on your keyboard... This will open a dialogue box and then hit enter. your cmd will open.. after that simply run this command:

```
pip install pygame
```

Then in your folder import it
In order to import it simply write:

```
import pygame
```

If your pip command shows you an error check the installation of python and try uninstalling python and then reinstalling it

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure the display has been set and the icon is set before the caption:

```
icon = pygame.image.load('icon.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
```