# How to set taskbar icon for pygame?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I have a pygame application that I want to set the taskbar icon for. I have tried

```py
import ctypes

myappid = 'mycompany.myproduct.subproduct.version' # arbitrary string
ctypes.windll.shell32.SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID(myappid)
```

but to no avail. I compiled it into a .exe with cx_Freeze and set the .exe icon there. When I run the program it sets the icon in the taskbar to be the default pygame icon. I have also set the icon for the pygame window with

```py
self.programIcon = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(currentPath, 'images', 'Logos', "railwaycontrollerbg.png"))
pygame.display.set_icon(self.programIcon)
```

Other info:

- Python 3.8 (32 bit)
- Pygame 2.0.0.dev10
- Windows 10 latest version

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing the application and taskbar icon - Python/Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14900510/changing-the-application-and-taskbar-icon-python-tkinter)

Comment: This is the same question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14900510/changing-the-application-and-taskbar-icon-python-tkinter) . U copied the most voted answer to ask question. I think its not a good thing for StackOverflow.

Comment: @egemenakturk I tried the answers from that question and they did not work. That is why I included this one here so that people would not suggest it as I had already tried it.

Comment: Changing icon only in cx_freeze won't work. You need to change the icon in pygame window as well. Here is the thread on how to do it in pygame window https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271059/how-do-i-change-the-pygame-icon

Comment: @tan_an Sorry, I forgot to mention that I had already set the window icon for pygame as well.

Comment: Have you specified '.ico' file in cx_freeze setup ? If not try converting your image to ico and then use in cx_freeze

Comment: @tan_an The file is saved as favicon.ico already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I believe that the problem was the image I was using was to large. I swapped it out with a 32 x 32 version of the image and it worked perfectly. Thanks for your help.